# Unit tests for a template mock class

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest

Is there a way to deal with unit tests that are for template class? In my example, `UnitTestA` is a unit test class and I was wondering of adding common methods like `bool check()` in this case which could be used by different unit tests i.e `TEST_F`

`MockA` being a template would require `T` to be a part of `UnitTestA` so I made `check` a template function, but is there any way I could store `MockA` instance inside `UnitTestA`? Perhaps a shared pointer? Or I'd have to pass in to `check` everytime?

```c
template<typename T>
class A
{
   public:
   void foo();
};

template<typename T>
class MockA final : public A
{
   public:
   void foo() 
   {
     A::foo();
   }
};

// Unit Test
class UnitTestA
{
  // std::shared_ptr<MockA<T>> mockA; 
  public:
     template<typename T>
     bool check(MockA<T> mockA) 
     {
       mockA.foo(); 
       // do stuff
       return true;               // assuming it's true
     }    
 
};

TEST_F(UnitTestA, Test1)
{
  MockA<int> mockA;
  check(&mockA);
}
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. The shown code does not compile.

Comment: Have you tried TYPED_TEST?(http://google.github.io/googletest/reference/testing.html#TYPED_TEST)